# How to avoid native memory leak with ObjectAnimator on API 23?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-animation, objectanimator

I have API 23 tablet devices that need to run 24/7. One part of the UI is animated using ObjectAnimator to make it continually fade in and out. This, for some reason, causes **native** memory usage (from what I can see in Android Studio memory profiler) to slowly rise at a rate of about 40mb per day. The application then crashes after the native memory usage reaches around 300mb.

I've made the simplest possible demo of said problem.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.animated_view);

    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.ALPHA, 1);
    anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(4000);
    anim.start();
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.testanimationleak.MainActivity"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/animated_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="60dp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sl"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:alpha="0"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

My logcat gets filled with a lot of stuff like this around the time it crashes:

```
     android.os.DeadObjectException
     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
     at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:305)
     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1599)
     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearClientSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1590)
     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1616)
     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1635)
     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1228)
     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1242)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:283)
     at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:168)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-31 12:30:01.991 1188-15364/system_process I/ActivityManager: Low on memory:
01-31 12:30:01.991 1188-15364/system_process I/ActivityManager:   ntv   N     9907 kB: perfd (pid 12606) native
ntv   N     9181 kB: com.android.deskclock (pid 15351) native
ntv   N     6886 kB: surfaceflinger (pid 184) native
ntv   N     3908 kB: zygote (pid 242) native
ntv   N     3409 kB: mediaserver (pid 225) native
ntv   N     3033 kB: logd (pid 150) native
ntv   N     1195 kB: sdcard (pid 1255) native
ntv   N     1069 kB: drmserver (pid 224) native
ntv   N      866 kB: vold (pid 153) native
ntv   N      826 kB: netd (pid 218) native
ntv   N      547 kB: keystore (pid 230) native
ntv   N      515 kB: /init (pid 1) native
ntv   N     6497 kB: (Other native)
01-31 12:30:01.991 1188-15364/system_process I/ActivityManager:   sys   P    36800 kB: system (pid 1188) fixed
pers  P    23482 kB: com.android.systemui (pid 1277) fixed
pers  P     7842 kB: com.android.phone (pid 1760) fixed
fore  T   625994 kB: com.example.testanimationleak (pid 31543) top-activity
    741957 kB: TOTAL
01-31 12:30:01.991 1188-15364/system_process I/ActivityManager:   MemInfo: 22904 kB slab, 4788 kB shmem, 7208 kB vm alloc, 7136 kB page tables 2736 kB kernel stack
   716 kB buffers, 61788 kB cached, 23428 kB mapped, 32460 kB free
Free RAM: 71536 kB
Used RAM: 786729 kB
Lost RAM: 163523 kB
```

I've tried not using INFINITE repeat count, but instead starting a new animation after previous one completes, but there was no difference.

I've tried using View.SCALE_Y instead of View.ALPHA per suggestion by @pskink; there appears to be no leak in that case. So the problem is specifically when using ObjectAnimator with View.ALPHA.

I've tried it out on my phone, Nexus 5 (API 23), the same thing happens, although I couldn't leave it running for a week until memory usage causes a crash. It didn't happen on another Samsung S7 (API 24), but I don't think I can update the tablet devices I have so I need a solution that will work on API 23.

So how do I avoid this memory leak? Is this a bug on API 23? How do I analyze which part is causing a leak when it's in native memory (and I'm not even using NDK)?

Comment: is it really `ObjectAnimator` or the property you want to change? what happens if you use `View.SCALE_Y` instead? the same result?

Comment: It's a good idea - I've tried it out with SCALE_Y just now; I've let it run for about 30 minutes since the increase is slow. The native memory did not increase, while with View.ALPHA would usually increase it about 500kb in that same time. I'll add that to my question, but the problem still remains - how to make ObjectAnimator with View.ALPHA work without leaking?

Comment: try `ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "imageAlpha", 0, 255);`

Comment: or you could play with `View#setLayerType`, what does `View#getLayerType` return now?

Comment: It returns layer type 0 - none? Also, I ran a 30 minute test using "imageAlpha", it works, although the effect is a bit different from the one I need, since my image in the actual application is like an icon, and then I add a padding and a background to the image view to make it stand out from the background. Then the entire view fades in/out, while in this case only the image does. But that could be solved by using an image that has a background and border, I guess, so it is some kind of a solution.

Comment: so did you try software or hardware instead of none?

Comment: Am running demo code with "hardware" right now, but I always let it run for 30 minutes just to make sure that something is or isn't happening. So far 10 minutes in and it seems good. But I'll have to try that out with the full app as well, I don't know what kind of effect the hardware layer can have, and my app has a way more complex layout than this demo - including a VideoView running under the animated ImageView. Will reply then.